# Owerwrite to a div element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

My problem is, i am getting a html text os string doesnt matter what is it from jquery but when i printed it inside a div element it doesnt clean the old data inside.

div is so simple just like that

```
<div id=table runat=server>
```

and my script is here

```
function send(inputa, inputb) {

     var dataString = JSON.stringify({
         Id: inputa,
         Opt: inputb                 
     });

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "my.aspx/myfunction",
         data: dataString,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
             alert(result.d);  // here i can see calue is good
             $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo").empty(); // here i try to clean
             $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo").html(result.d);
            },
         error: function () {
             alert("Problem Occured");
         }
     });

 }
```

Please let me know what is not good here. I tried all functions html text val, i need something more i guess. my output has old values aswell.

Comment: try $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo").html('');

Comment: `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo").html('');`

Comment: Did you check to see that $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo") return the element you trying to change? It may be returning an empty set and as such will not assigned any thing.

Comment: @iceless im sorry its not working at all i am still seeing old data in div aswell

Comment: I've seen issues before with jQuery and divs that aren't closed.  Try it with `<div id="table" runat="server"></div>`

Comment: also log result.d and check

Comment: result.d is perfect on alert, its ready to populated. @ScottW how can i try it with <div id="table" runat="server"></div> in which element shall i populate than? why im seeing old data inside thats my problem, its killing all

Comment: Just make sure that your `div` is being properly closed.

Comment: http://www.theextremewebdesigns.com/blog/using-jquery-add-html-to-div-easy-examples-to-add-html-to-div/ i found this link but do you know what is e.preventDefault(); ?
is it relaited with it?

Comment: @speranza4ever preventDefault is not related to clearing content.

Comment: I am checking div id at source code, its all true. but when i print its not happenning. I am sure its because of .net , im sure php developers dont have this problem. @AlbertXing

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div>` is:

```
<div id=table runat=server>
```

so instead of

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo").empty(); // here i try to clean
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tablo").html(result.d);
```

use the correct `id`:

```
$("#table").empty(); // this is not necessary
$("#table").html(result.d); // this will clear the existing content
```

Comment: Asp.net is changing table name, problem is not printing inside div, problem starts when i see old data inside aswell. You better read it please.

Comment: @speranza4ever the `empty()` and `html()` method will anyways clear the existing html. If it's not happening then it's not being applied. maybe your selector is wrong: try using `name` or a class name selector instead of `id` so that asp doesn't manipulate it. Or maybe the old data also is coming from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after checking many times, I found what the problem was: I am using div element in table content and writing table columns inside this div. And when I render page this div is kicked out of table content. And jQuery is changing content like I wanted but table was still remaining. To fix this, I used table id and deleted all div elements in table.

Issue solved.

Thanks everybody for answers.